# A p-channel MOSFET driver with 3.2 V logic

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I'm trying to design a driver for a load that is connected to ground and needs 24 VDC. My schematic is this:

[image]

In simulation, I obtain the expected values for V<sub>GS</sub> that I expect to move from 0 to about -10 V, but when V<sub>GS</sub> is 0 V, I expect the MOSFET being open, so V<sub>OUT</sub> being 0 V, instead V<sub>OUT</sub> moves around 24 V... where am I wrong?

[image]

The MOSFET is *IRF9540* and R<sub>L</sub> is 2.2 kΩ. I omit other components values, because I think V<sub>GS</sub> is what is supposed to be, but maybe I'm wrong at this point as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your P-channel MOSFET is connected backwards. Source should go to +24V

Comment: Yes you are right, I tryed and it works, at least in simulation, I was misleaded by the fact I read somewhere drain and source in a mosfet can be exchanged, but of course I did not get it right.

Comment: @FelicePollano Drain and source in many JFETs can be exchanged but in almost all discrete MOSFETs the bulk is connected internally to the source so there's a parallel "body" diode that conducts in reverse.

Answer (score 3):

You have T1 in backwards. Connect source to +24V.

Although a MOSFET is fairly symmetric and would work either way round all discrete MOSFETs have a body-diode between drain and source.

By putting it in the circuit backwards the body-diode will conduct even when VGS is zero.